# How to get 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th child element of a specific <div id="target"> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Is that clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the CSS3 [`nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) selector. eg. 2nd:

```
$('#target>:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

...and if you need them all:

```
var lowerBoundary = 0;
var upperBoundary = 4;

var wrappedSet = $("#target > *")
                  .filter
                  (
                    function(i)
                    {
                      return i >= lowerBoundary && i <= upperBoundary;
                    }
                  );

alert(wrappedSet.size());
```

This sets wrappedSet to contain the first five elements of target as a group.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do something like

```
 $("#target > :lt(5)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#testdiv > :lt(5)');
```

It will return all the elements in a result set less than n (zero based)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="testdiv">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
        <input id="Text2" type="text" />
        <input id="Text3" type="text" />
        <input id="Text4" type="text" />
        <input id="Text5" type="text" />
        <input id="Text6" type="text" />
        <input id="Text7" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var items = $('#testdiv > :lt(5)');

</script>

</html>
```

So the above code will return first five elements in this case first five textboxes.